# How do I edit HTML files directly?

Tags: php, database, file, blogs, scripting

I'm trying to build a blog/messageboard that uses static HTML files to serve content. I know MovableType used to manage their blog engiene this way, but using Perl CGI scripts. How do I edit/append to HTML files preferebly using PHP? What other methods would people reccommend?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In php there are many file manipulation functions. [Read more about them here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.filesystem.php). Here's a quick example creating an html file:

```
<?php

file_put_contents('an_html_file.html', "This will be in the html file.");

?>
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want to just edit the files as raw text:

http://us.php.net/manual/en/ref.filesystem.php

If you want to work with actual HTML DOM:

http://us.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php

(and specifically, [loadHTMLFile()](http://us.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtmlfile.php) and [saveHTMLFile()](http://us.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.savehtmlfile.php))

Answer (score 2):

Depending on how much work you want to do you could just use [fopen](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php) and friends.