# Add html code to an html file from another one with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have 2 html files `a.html` and `b.html` and i want to write some javascript code to the `a.html` file that can add, edit, or delete html code to the  `b.html` file.

Comment: So we know what you wish to achieve, now lets have a look at what you have tried? Where is your source code (Attempts) and what isn't working? Where is the issue?

Comment: You might find this helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1413691/how-do-i-edit-html-files-directly

Comment: Why is this marked as duplicate for **Include** html page? The OP isn't asking how to include anything. The OP is asking how to modify `b.html` from `a.html` Add/Edit/Delete elements, not include them. >> i want to **write some javascript code to the `a.html` file** that can `add`, `edit`, or `delete` html code **to** the  `b.html` file << If this is going to be marked as duplicate I think the answer URL should be set to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1413691/how-do-i-edit-html-files-directly

Answer (score 0):

You have only one choice to use AJAX. If you are using jQuery, you can do something like:

```js
$(function () {
  $("#b").load("b.html");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>I am in <code>a.html</code></p>
<p id="b">B comes here</p>
```

The above script is basically an AJAX request to load the contents of `b.html` that is found along with the `a.html` in the same directory, inside the `<p>` with an `id` of `b`.

Sorry, I forgot to mention. To make the AJAX call easier, I have added a library called [jQuery](http://jquery.com/), which provides a lot of functionality.

Comment: This isn't going to edit or delete parts of the html file though is it? This is just going to load `b.html` into `a.html` I think what the OP is wanting is `a.html` to be the editor for `b.html` like a CMS

Comment: @NewToJS It replaces the contents inside the `<p>` tag alone. No changes to other parts. `:)`

Comment: Exactly, so `a.html` isn't adding/editing/removing existing content in `b.html`. This is just setting the innerHTML of the paragraph tag in `a.html` with the content from `b.html`

Comment: I haven't used jquery or AJAX before so i just copy this?
There isn't another way so I can also edit or remove code?

Comment: This also requires jQuery which isn't tagged in the question so I think it would be very relevant to point out how to link to the jQuery library as people who are new to development may not know how to do so hence it not being tagged.

Comment: @Chris if you want to alter existing source code I would recommend researching some server-side languages. See which one you find best to use.